# Raspberry pi os Bullseye 64bit ssh password not 'raspberry' anymore?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, wpa-supplicant

I've been having problems with the raspberry pi imager so just downloaded the latest 64bit os from their site. Then used Belena Etcher to etch the image. Made the ssh file and the wpa_supplicant file.

It's showing on the network but for some reason I can't connect via ssh via terminal with ssh pi@ip.address, it asks for a password but when I enter 'raspberry' it won't work. Has something changed?

Answer (score 10):

This answer is an extension of the answer provided by @Gotenks.

Create a file named **userconf** in the boot folder to create a user. The contents of the file are as follows

```
username:password-hash
```

The password-hash is generated using the following command

```bash
echo "password" | openssl passwd -6 -stdin
```

For example **boot/userconf** can be:

```
pi:$6$38HiUnLhwlE1DRdL$MHHb6/OsyAlZNqmW7igj333g/CRwG/g5nls7ylTEqZZg9rOIM/cUvE962.5x6M0ONMz/r6OlBy/G6f4v8zrH51
```

### Ubuntu way

If you use Ubuntu as host system then you can configure password very easy. Mount, make cd to your pi's boot folder and run script:
[image: how mount image]

```
cat <<EOF > userconf
pi:$(echo "password" | openssl passwd -6 -stdin)
EOF
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no longer a default username/password.

Have a look at: https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/

Comment: Thanks for that. Just saw a couple of videos spring up on youtube about it too. Seems it's a recent change.

Comment: This saved my day

Comment: Well, they should at least put some kind of warning on the download page. You got my vote @Gotenks - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a headless Pi (say, the Pi Zero W), you may find it usefull that the official ["Raspberry Pi Imager"](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/) supports setting up an ssh user account (and the Wifi, the keyboard layout, the timezone, ...) for the image being flashed. Just use the "settings" button at the lower right corner:

[image: the settings button]